# XSLT identity attributes

Tags: xslt, identity

I got a question about the identity. I change the identity transformation template as followong:

```
<xsl:template match="node() | @*">
<xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" />
</xsl:copy>
```

I changed the xsl:apply-templates processing instruction by deleting the " | @*" of the select. WHY does it not copy any attributes?

Comment: Why would it? The template only copies the nodes to which it is applied - and you have made sure it is never applied to an attribute. -- See also: https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#section-Processing-Model

Comment: You changed it to remove the part that copies attributes, and you're surprised that it no longer copies attributes?

Comment: Perhaps you hadn't worked out that `node()` means `child::node()`, and that the child axis does not include attributes?

Comment: I know that child::node() does not match any attribute-node. BUT: The template matches any attribute-node and xsl:copy copies the current context-node into the output. So thats the point why I dont get it, that it does not copy any attribute-node. The XSLT transformation should call that template for any attribute-node, isn't it? (It is more specialized than the implied rule for attribute-nodes) I hope you can understand what I mean or whats my point.

Comment: @MichaelKay may be you understand what I mean?

Comment: When your template rule matches an element, it shallow-copies the element (which doesn't touch the attributes) and then it applies templates to the children. It never applies templates to attributes, and if you don't apply-templates to a node, then it doesn't matter whether or not there are any templates to process that node; they will never be activated.

Comment: Thank you so much, I got it!